# Spring boot no reconoce nueva DB AWS

Tags: spring, heroku

Tengo una aplicacion web spring boot con una base mysql. Inicialmente hice deploy en heroku con una base de datos crearDB como addon.
Despues al necesitar conectar otra aplicacion a esa DB y al no poder hacerlo por restriccion de heroku tuve que crear una DB en aws, modifiqué el archivo properties con las nuevas credenciales y url pero la aplicación sigue apuntando a primera db de heroku.

Como puedo hacer que mi aplicacion reconozca los nuevos parametros de base de datos?

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://hhosorno.cwkxmohzhisa.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com/hho?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = xxxxxx
spring.datasource.password = xxxxxx
```

Comment: Puedes compartir tu archivo `application.properties`?

Comment: actualicé la pregunta para poner los parametros de conexión. Como antecedente tambien es que durante un commit a heroku antes de cambiar la base de datos tuve incluido el .properties en el archivo gitingore, pero despues lo quité

Answer (score 0):

Primero debe verificar que en su pom.xml exista la dependencia de MySQL:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Después debe agregar los siguientes atributos en el archivo `.properties` (o yml):

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://IP.DEL.SERVIDOR.MYSQL:3306/db_example
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=ThePassword
spring.datasource.driver-class-name =com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Comment: Para más y mejor información este es el link oficial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/